# How to access an item that start with a #

Tags: c#, json

Unable to access an item in JSON format due to illegal characters in c#

The JSON is a JObject

```cs
info.image[1]["#text"] // returns invalid string
info.image[1].text // returns null
info.image[1].#text // Invalid syntax
```

```cs
{
"image": 
[{"#text":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/bd2a669ca0e58fa33c609e0adfde5d72fe4e5bf5","size":"small"},
{"#text":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/a88cfa6206740a01b713554f2510af239fd4493e","size":"medium"},
{"#text":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/0c8a93d0a56f2285e4f27b9592f824a4498ca960","size":"large"},
{"#text":"https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/0c8a93d0a56f2285e4f27b9592f824a4498ca960","size":"huge"}]
}
```

I want to be able to retrieve the link

Comment: And what C# code are you trying that does not work?

Comment: you will probably need to use property attribute [JsonProperty("#text")] using Newtonsoft.Json in your model to access it.

Comment: Maybe try escaping hash sign either by slash or @ sign before string?

Comment: If you deserialize to, say, `<Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>>`, then you can have `info["image"][0]["#text"], ["image"][1]["size"]` etc. (just an example), but `#` is not a problem.

Comment: Can't reproduce, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/imEHaF.  `string s = info.image[1]["#text"];` works perfectly.  And if you don't want to use `dynamic` you can do `string s = (string)info["image"][1]["#text"];`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/S7ym2k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

# is an invalid value for attributes in C #.

To be able to retrieve the values you need to use JsonProperty in your JsonClass.

```
public class YourClass
{
    [JsonProperty("#text")]
    public string text {get; set;}
}
```